# SWIFT: How to scale down a UIGraphics/imageContext without losing quality?

Tags: swift, uigraphicscontext

I have a box that the user taps on to draw circles. On the screen, the graphics are tack sharp and look great.  I also give the user the ability to email or text the graphic, however, the quality is pretty poor.  I also have to draw the circles back on the box at the proper position.

The box assets are @2x 908 × 534 pixels and @3x 1362 × 801 pixels.  I'd like to scale down the image so I don't have to send out such a large PNG file.

```
let hockeyNetImageView   = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 340, height: 200))
hockeyNetImageView.image = UIImage(named: "hockeyNet")

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 340, height: 200))

let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
hockeyNetImageView.layer.render(in: context)
let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

//Resize the image
let size = (img.size).applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0))

let hasAlpha = true
let scale: CGFloat = 0.0

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((img.size), !hasAlpha, scale)
img.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: size))

let scaleImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

goalieNetArray.append(UIImagePNGRepresentation(scaleImage!)!)

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: You are using the wrong version of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`. Use the one that has a `scale` parameter.

Comment: Just noticed you are calling it twice. Only the 2nd one is correct.